# Mac OS X bug: Desktop & Screen Saver: image alignment preference is ignored

Tags: macos, screensaver, desktop-customization, alignment

I have my desktop background set to rotate through a folder of images.

Even though I have the alignment drop-down list set to "Center", the images still render as "Fill to Screen".

When I change the list value to something else, then back to "Center", OR I manually click on a different image to display, well, that image is rendered as "Center".  But all images that follow (via the "Change picture every x minutes" checkbox) are rendered as Fill to Screen.

Any fix to this bug?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X?

Comment: Leopard.      d

Answer (score 0):

On Snow Leopard, this bug is not present. My images when set to cycle at Center alignment works fine and stays centered.

If you *must* have rotating wallpaper images set as Center, you might want to try an Automator workflow.

Comment: p.s What are the resolution of your images in your wallpaper folder? Have you verified the bug by choosing another folder with let's say, wallpapers @ max resolutions from example, http://www.interfacelift.com?